# How to reply when someone says "How dare you do it"

Tags: grammar, idioms, modal-verbs

I have no idea how to answer this:

> How dare you do it
>   or
>   How dare you do something that is unusual

Is this a correct way of replying

> I dare it because I needed it

Are there any other ways? Could you please help me answering my question.

Comment: What are you trying to ask here? Can you clarify your actual question? This can be "answered" in a thousand ways.

Comment: Sorry!what i am asking is if I did something wrong to somebody and he said that how do you dare to touch me/things at this point how can i answer him?how to response to this question.

Comment: You can either explain your reason (which we can't know) for touching his things, or you can apologize. Or you can take another path. This is an English language site. What you are looking for is *advice*.

Comment: I guess you are not getting me yet.I meant to ask is should i answer like - I dare it cause i needed it.or any other ways?

Comment: Please edit your question, explain exactly what your request is. Even if you just copy&paste your comments IN the question that would already be an improvement. E.g. Is the reply: *"I dare it because I needed it"* correct and idiomatic?

Comment: My answer (when in just the *wrong* mood) to such rhetorical questions is *How dare you ask such a rhetorical question!?*

Comment: [How dare you + v](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/how+dare+you)

Answer (score 4):

The 'questions' you ask about are frequently rhetorical - no answer as such is expected. The meaning is similar to "I am shocked/angry that you should dare ..." . As medica noted above, you can either explain your reason, or apologise. You could also do many other things: get angry, run away, etc. There is no single answer to your question.

Comment: Dear tunny,appreciate your answer but i am sorry what i was about to ask you was - if somebody tells me that how can i answer him or her in a particular way is my concern.Thanks.

Comment: +1. This is a rhetorical question, and does not ask for an answer. Ignore the fact that it is a question. Either apologise or just say "I needed it" and shrug in indifference. You being insistent that someone give you an answer is like insisting on an answer to "Who is the current King of France", even though you are repeatedly told France *doesn't have a king*.

Comment: Please see the edit. The OP in one of his comments pinpointed the "technical" difficulty.

Comment: Looks like the question is doomed to be closed, despite my edit :( Four votes to close it because it's "unclear".